# Editable fields in views

Tags: views, entities

I am hiding a field using hook_form_alter, because I only want to be able to edit this field in views. then, I used the [Editable Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) to display this field. Now, my problem is that when I press the save button, all of my nodes are saved.

Is there any way to only save nodes where this field has been edited?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you're looking for the [jEditable inline content editing](https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable) module. I tried this module for one of my project and working fine.

Using this module you can do inline edits for individual fields. you can make inline edits at node output and views output too.

Note: Right now There is only dev version available  for Drupal 7x so make sure to install and test on local instance first.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, there's [Views Entity Form Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_entity_form_field).  There's [an issue with patches](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_entity_form_field/issues/2984618) for what you're trying to do.

However, [jEditable inline content editing](https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable) is still available in Drupal 8.  So choose the one that works better for your use case.